# setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated affects JFrame resize behaviour

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, look-and-feel

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test{


public static void main(String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();

            jp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            //frame.getContentPane().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            //frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            frame.getContentPane().add(jp);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

It behaves exactly the way I want. User can resize the `JFrame` but it'll always be large enough to hold 200px x 200px `JPanel`. But when I remove:

`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`

user can resize `JFrame` to any size.

Why does default look and feel decoration affect resizing? How can i make it work without `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`? I know I can set frames minimum size manually (`JFrame#setMinimumSize(new Dimension dim)`) and I will if there is no smarter solution.

I'm using jdk 1.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: +1 great question. I would like to find out too.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=18bfd2cf9514c46ab3836f022fee?bug_id=4320050) use to be a bug, the page speaks of work arounds like:

- override `setSize()` and check if the new size is less than the desired
- inside `paint(Graphics g)` of `JFrame` check height and width and "re-create" frame to new minimum size

however a person claims it to be fixed as the original example issued for the bug proposal omitted the call to `setMinimumSize(...)`, this is needed because JFrame does not enforce minimum size

Here is the snippet which shows that persons' code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication118 {

    private final Dimension m_dim = new Dimension(200, 150);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JavaApplication118().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {

        // JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test") {

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                return m_dim;
            }
            
        };

        frame.setMinimumSize(m_dim);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents(frame);

        // frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        jp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));//for testing

        frame.getContentPane().add(jp);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The snippet overrode `getMinimumSize()` though this seems redundant after calling `setMinimumSize(..)`, I kept it included as that's how I found the snippet (I did remove the overridden  `getPreferredSize()` method of the `JFrame` which the snippet included).

Comment: that's outdated: as of 1.6, Window guarantees to respect a min size, unfortunately only if explicitly set by window.setMinimumSize

Comment: @kleopatra yup that's what made me think that calling those methods are not 'bad'. +1 to ur iszminimumsizeset override

Comment: it's a singularity, probably because it's a top-level container. Its behaviour is only guaranteed as far as the underlying OS guarantees it. All other setXXSize are still evil ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Why does default look and feel decoration affect resizing?

Because then the window sizing is under the complete control of the LAF while dragging: The mouseHandler installed by (f.i.) MetalRootPaneUI doesn't resize the window below the min returned by the LayoutManager. Without setting the frame's minimumSize, you can still decrease its size programatically.

The only way (unfortunately) to enforce a window's minimum size *always* is to manually set it. Unfortunate, as that implies keeping track of dynamic changes of that minimum and update it as appropriate.

A snippet to play with (un/comment the defaultDecoration and frame min setting)

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Dimension m = getMinimumSize();
        // visualize the min
        g.drawRect(0, 0, m.width - 1, m.height -1);
    }

};
// BEWARE: for demonstration only, NEVER do in production code 
panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
panel.setPreferredSize(panel.getMinimumSize());
final JXFrame frame = new JXFrame("", true);
Action action = new AbstractAction("resize") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        LOG.info("succeeded? " + frame.getSize());
    }
};
panel.add(new JButton(action));
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
// set minimum is required to enforce the minimum
frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getMinimumSize());
```

**Update**

Looking at the Window source, turns out that you can have auto-magic dynamic respect of min size by overriding isMinimumSizeSet and returning true uncondinionally:

```
final JXFrame frame = new JXFrame("", true) {
    @Override
    public boolean isMinimumSizeSet() {
        return true;
    }
};
...
// no longer needed
// frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getMinimumSize());
```

not tested for side-effects, though